# Is it "safe" to declare using aliases inside a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I navigated through the web and through other StackOverflow posts, but I didn't find any suitable answer to my question.

The question is: supposing I have and header file, in which I have a namespace, and inside this namespace I want to declare a variable with a very complex type; is it "safe" to use aliases to simplifiy readability of this variable type?

I leave you an example to better understand my question:

```
namespace abc
 {
  using str_pair_map = std::map <std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>>;
  str_pair_map this_map;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by safe?

Comment: @Bathsheba I mean that in this way I don't have any "general" problem with other variables / types names declaration and that this is considered a "good" practice in C++.

Comment: It's safer to declare this inside a namespace than outside. The concern is that someone else would use the same symbol, and that's much more likely to be a problem in the global namespace than within `namespace abc`

Comment: Declaring a `using` inside a `namespace` is safe.  And is perfectly acceptable good practice.

Comment: @TimRandall thanks. For "safer" you mean also that this is a good practice, or however it would be better to avoid it in general?

Comment: Aliases for complex types is a good practice. Whether you really need such a complex type is a separate question. Typically, it's a red flag.

Comment: Instead of using `std::pair`, nearly always it's better to define a class.

Comment: @eerorika I completely agree and I would add `std::tuple` to this rule too.

Comment: @MarekR I preferred using map of string and pair since I always used maps to represent my variables in my project. It may be less suitable to use a pair only for a single object type or create a class and let maps for all the others, I think.

Comment: @GianlucaBianco problem with `std::pair` and `std:tuple` in none generic code is that fields in in are not named (in case of pair not named specific to the problem). This makes code harder to read and maintain. I quite often accouter some code which returns one of this and I have trouble figure out what exactly each field is and what is it its purpose. That it is why I prefer see code which returns struct with informative name and informative name of fields.

Comment: Seems like you might want a struct for that value instead of a pair. Also, I’d worry about race conditions on a global mutable variable like that. But the `using` is fine.