# What is a better data structure to replace a map o sets?

Tags: c++

recently I wrote a post in which I asked for help in a problem I had in a C++ code. However, some people focused on a definition I put in one of my codes, which is:

```
std::map <std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> map_example;
```

saying that this is considered a bad definition and that I should replace it.

I want to ask you if you can suggest me a better way to represent this data structure in a C++ code (possibly I want to avoid tuples), thanks.

**EDIT**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70081802/is-it-safe-to-declare-using-aliases-inside-a-namespace) the link to the question I talked above.

Comment: why did they say it would be "bad" ? Everything can be "good" or "bad" depending on what you actually need and use it for.

Comment: Some folk don't like `std::pair` since you can't give the pair constituents meaningful names. But I don't see a problem with it, especially if your code is clean and readable.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I edited the question linking you the post I talked above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common concern against `std::pair` is poor naming of its members. Your code will be sprinkled with `first` and `second` when you probably could use better names.

Compare

```
struct customer_name_and_company {
     std::string customer_name;
     std::string company;
};

std::map<std::string, customer_name_and_company> m;
for (const auto& e : m) {
    std::cout << e.customer_name << " " << e.company << "\n";
}
```

with the same code using a `std::pair`:

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::string,std::string> m;
for (const auto& e : m) {
    std::cout << e.first << " " << e.second << "\n";
}
```

Neither the type nor the loop using the type uses proper names. Names are important! Consider you are looking only at the loop, then `customer_name` and `company` immediately tell you what those members are, while `first` and `second` requires you to track down previous definitions to make any sense out of the code.

`std::pair` is good for generic code when you simply have no way to give names better than `first` and `second` because you don't know what they are. Also the standard library makes extensive use of `std::pair` (for example [`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) and others). I suppose that is to avoid inflation of simple types that would pollute the `std` namespace. In your own code, on the other hand, any variable and type you can give a meaningful name, means more readable code.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct customer_name_and_company 
{
    customer_name_and_company(const std::string& _customer_name, const std::string& _company) :
    customer_name{_customer_name},
    company{_company} {}
    
    
    std::string customer_name;
    std::string company;
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map <std::string, customer_name_and_company> umap {{"banana", customer_name_and_company{"1", "2"}}};
}
```

A similar implementation to the one above, but I consider it more efficient with `std::unordered_map`, than with `std::map`, in case there will be no collisions (in which case the complexity will be O(n)), but otherwise the complexity is O(1), for all operations (delete, search, insert), compared to O(logN).

Comment: not a big deal, but it is just too obvious where you took this code from and that you didn't bother to make that clear in the answer :/. Btw `customer_name_and_company` doesnt need the user defined constructor, without it it is an aggregate.

Comment: oh... are you refering to the other answer when you write "the one above" ? Please note that "above" depends on how one sorts the answers.